# How to execute a loop with sequential summation?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with this loop:

```js
var arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];
    
var sum = 0;
    
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  sum += parseInt(item);
  console.log(sum)
});
```

At the moment, I get this result:

```
5
9
18
24
28
```

But how to make sure that the result always starts with 0 and ends with the penultimate digit, i.e. it should look like this:

```
0
5
9
18
24
```

Comment: Consider looking at using `reduce`

Comment: If you just want the logs in that order. You can move the `console.log` line up one.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that is the wrong choice here.

Comment: @connexo why is that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Now that I think about it, agreed that `reduce` might be a good choice, even here. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the `console.log` up one line. If you want the `28` to be logged also, then add a `console.log(sum)` after the loop.

```js
var arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];

var sum = 0;

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(sum)
  sum += parseInt(item);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the value to a sum and make the sum usable in the next loop.

This solution uses a take first approach and changes a value later in the run.

```
[value, changePart][index]
```

```js
var array = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4],
    result = array.map((s => v => [s, s += v][0])(0));
    
console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder some codes like this:

```js
    var arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];
        
    var sum = 0;
        
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log(sum)
      sum += parseInt(item);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, just move up the console log line, that gets you what you declared your desired outcome.

```js
const arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];
    
let sum = 0;
    
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(sum);
  sum += parseInt(item);
});
```

To achieve the same end result while logging the steps, you could also use `Array.prototype.reduce`. That would spare you to work on scoped variable, but instead simply assign the result of the reduce call to a variable.

```js
const arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];
    
let sum = arr.reduce(function(accumulator, value) {
  console.log(accumulator)
  return accumulator += value
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];

var sum = 0;

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(sum)
  sum += parseInt(item);
});
```

Simple display your counter before you interfere with it. You result will always start with 0 though since you define `sum` to be 0 before your loop.

Your output now should look like what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

First log the sum value

```
var arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];

var sum = 0;

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(sum)
  sum += parseInt(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do that in a lot of different ways. Moving `console.log` one line up can be one. However, if you don't want to move your `console.log`, please refer to the below code where I used two `sum` variables:

```
var arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];

var sum = 0;
var sum2 = 0;

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  sum += sum2;
  sum2 = parseInt(item);
  console.log(sum)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered but it's worth mentioning that the forEach api actually has 3 parameters not just 1 and you can use that, here's an example:

```
var arr = [5, 4, 9, 6, 4];

var sum = 0;

arr.forEach((item,i)=>{
    //"item" is the item
    //"i" is the current index
    //the third argument is the whole array
    sum += parseInt(item);
    console.log(sum);//as pointed out by @Jacob you can just move this line up
    if(i === arr.length+1) return; //but you can also just stop the iteration on the exact index you want like this
});
```

This is not the best solution for your needs, as you're using a sum operation every iteration to check the index, but it's more flexible and it's good to know the api offers the current index.